# buildbot: buildbot.slave.commands.SVN vs. buildbot.steps.source.SVN

Tags: svn, project-management, build-process, continuous-integration, buildbot

Buildbot question:

When to use each of these classes: `buildbot.slave.commands.SVN` and `buildbot.steps.source.SVN`?

I want the class that is used to check out a project from svn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider the `buildbot.slave.*` classes as internal.

What you should pass to `builder.addStep` is an instance of `buildbot.steps.source.SVN`.